# Grails searchable search BigDecimal range

Tags: search, grails, range, searchable

I have Grails project with domain that has multiple fields, among them I have field 'price'.
I added searchable plugin to the project and it works fine, via general search:

```
def searchResults = searchableService.search(params.q, params)
```

Now I need to add price search via range. Example: price between $100 and $200.
I tried following but it doesn't work:

```
def searchResults = searchableService.search({
    queryString(params.q)
    lt("price", params.pmax?.trim().toBigDecimal())
},params)
```

How do I implement range search?
Does it matter what kind of data type it is: Integer, BigDecimal, Long?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a search by range like this:

```
def searchResults = searchableService.search(params){
    must(queryString(params.q) {
        ge('price', params.pmax as BigDecimal)
        le('price', params.pmin as BigDecimal)
    })
}
```

[EDITED]

My previous solution doesn't work perfectly.
The right way to do search with numbers with searchable, you need first add this in your domain class:

```
searchable {
     price index: "not_analyzed", format : "0000000000"
}
```

And then to do the search:

```
def searchResults = yourDomainClass.search("price:[" + (params.pmin ? params.pmin.trim().padLeft(10, "0") : "*"  )+ " TO " + (params.pmax ? params.pmax.trim().padLeft(10, "0") : "*"  )+ "]"
```

All that is need because when your data is indexed, is also textified.

http://brettscott.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/lucene-number-range-search-integers-floats/

http://grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+FAQ